# error on RadioButton IsChecked

Tags: silverlight, radio-button

```
if (noob.IsChecked)
        { 
           //blah blah
        }
```

When I try to use this code to see if RadioButton Name="noob" is checked, I get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/778db998-d92e-494d-83b1-5be66e0ebe5c/

Comment: Okay, so this would work then to check if it is checked? if (noob.IsChecked.HasValue && noob.IsChecked.Value == true) { }

Comment: I think so, I don't have a way to test it but it looks right.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and is more concise:

```
if (noob.IsChecked == true)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

Note that it does not throw an exception if `noob.IsChecked` is `null`, so it is not necessary to first check `HasValue`.